# JS: weird object comparison behavior

Tags: javascript, object, variables, comparison

Given this code:

```js
const name = { name: 'amy' };

function greet(person) {
    if (person == { name: 'amy' }) {
        return 'hey amy';
    } else {
        return 'hey there';
    }
}

console.log(
    greet(name)  // 'hey amy'
);

console.log(
    greet({ name:'amy' })  // 'hey there'
);

console.log(name == { name: 'amy' });  // true

console.log(name === { name: 'amy' });  // false

console.log(Object.is(name, { name: 'amy' }));  // false
```

Why does double-equals comparison return `true` when using the `name` variable, but not an object literal?

First, I thought that maybe it's because the objects have the same memory address, but as one can see it's not true.

Moreover, if we turn things upside-down and define the variable inside the function, the comparison returns `false`! (It is not shown in the code but you can check it out)

I'm seriously confused and will appreciate the explanation.

EDIT:
[Here](https://repl.it/repls/ImmaterialUnfitBytes) is where I have tested the code. Nodejs and browser console in Chrome give me the regular results, how it should be. So maybe it is something about the interpreter.

Comment: i see a different result as you mentioned. (just the expected one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the use of the word `name` for your variable.

In a browser, the `window` object has a `name` property that must always be a string. If you try to assign something to it that is not a string, it will be converted to one.

Then, when you compare an object with a string, the object will also be converted and the two strings compared. This is why you see it sometimes return true. Example:

```js
// This will end up being assigned to window.name, and will be converted to a string.
var name = {name: "amy"}
console.log(name) // [object Object]

// Then, when you compare that to another object using ==, the object will also be converted to string.
console.log(name == {name: "amy"}) // true, because the string [object Object] is equal to itself.
```

Change the name of the variable to anything else, or use `let` or `const`, and the problem should disappear:

```js
// This will end up being assigned to window.other, but isn't converted to string
var other = {name: "amy"}
console.log(other) // {"name": "amy"}

// Now, both are objects, and unless they are the exact same object, comparing two objects is always false.
console.log(other == {name: "amy"}) // false, no two distinct objects are ever equal
```

```js
// Using let will not assign this variable to window.
let name = {name: "amy"}
console.log(name) // {"name": "amy"}

// Again, now we compare two distict objects, which always results in false.
console.log(name == {name: "amy"}) // false
```

Comment: Wow! Changing the name has made the deal! Thank you so much.
However, using `let` or `const` along with `name` variable name leads to the same weird behavior!

Comment: Is your code going through a transpilation step that converts `let`/`const` to `var`? As you can see, `let` or `const` should fix it, but maybe the behavior is different on the environment you run it on. But my suspicion is that somehow it is being converted to `var`.

Comment: Oh... Can't check it, most probably it does.
But when checked it within a browser, `let` and `const` behave as you say.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You assume that Javascript will perform the comparision with `==` as you are thinking of it in your mind, but it is not. But as this is a custom object you can't expect Javascript to hand you a custom implementation out of the box. You should implement it yourself.

The only case where this would work is when you use the `===` operator to check whether the object are the same but by their memory address, thus skipping any `custom-object-data-based` comparison whatsoever.